# Can not convert int to Fuzzy initialization

Tags: c++

I just tried fuzzy logic code by c++ and for one part of my code that is in below i have some errors.

The code part is:

```
void setup(){


Fuzzy * fuzzy = new fuzzy();
```

and the following errors related to that are :

```
error: expected type-specifier before fuzzy 

error: cannot convert int to Fuzzy in initialization
```

do anyone knows what are these errors for?

Comment: Capitalization error?, `new Fuzzy();` Can you provide an example that gives more context?

Comment: You most likely don't need (and shouldn't want) that `new`.

Comment: Are you sure you need a dynamically allocated `Fuzzy`?

Comment: Did you import the header `Fuzzy` is located in? Check if the naming is same, including its casing

Answer (score 5):

This is almost certianly a typo:

```
Fuzzy* fuzzy = new fuzzy();
```

Should be:

```
Fuzzy* fuzzy = new Fuzzy();
                   ^
                Note Case!
```

Comment: Irony: "This is almost certianly a typo".

Comment: @Casey: shuretenly? I am bad at tiping.

Comment: Muphry's law strikes again.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a capitalization error, this:

```
Fuzzy* fuzzy = new fuzzy();
```

should be:

```
Fuzzy* fuzzy = new Fuzzy();
```

although, I don't think that it accounts for all the errors but without more code for context it is hard to know.